# PHP cannot find class file

Tags: php, templates

Normaly I would include my class file before I create an object. My question is how I can include a class file only in my main file and then use it method in another class? Here is my code:

main file:

```
require_once("class.a.php");
require_once("class.b.php");

var $a;

function main () {
     $a = new class.a();
     $b = new class.b();
}
```

class b:

```
 class b {
    var $a;

    function __construct() {
          $this->a = class.a::method();
    }          
 }
```

This seems to work in some older PHP version but it gives an error file class.a.php not found in some new PHP version.

Edit: I've corrected my question: class.b uses direct calls to method from class.a. This gives me an error class.a.php not found. I can fix this error when I add a require_once("class.a.php") to class.b.php like this:

```
require_once("class.a.php");
class b {
    var $a;

    function _constructor() {
          $this->a = class.a::method();
    }          
 }
```

But then I have two includes and also this doesn't work with an update version of php?

Comment: Are you trying to pass $a to class.b?

Comment: It's not my project, I just try to fix it and I came across this template. I'm getting this error file not found and the problem is that the guy use this constructor and calls a method from class a.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage dependency autoloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362957/how-to-manage-dependency-autoloading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your classes as stated on other answers. Make them as "a" and "b". You have to use dependency injection on class b.

```
b {
    public $a;

    function __construct(a $a) {
        $this->a = $a; // now you have the instance of class.a in your class.b
   }          
}
```

And your main.php

```
require_once("class.a.php");
require_once("class.a.php");

function main () {
     $a = new a()
     $b = new b($a);
     $b->a->method(); // call the method of a
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, `new class.a()` should create a syntax error as `.` is not a valid operator anywhere apart from string concatenation. You want

```
class a {
    // do something
}

$a = new a();
```

As to the `require_once`, well, once you have included or required a file in a PHP script, all of the classes/functions/variables/constants/etc. will continue to persist in all other files which are included *after* the require. So your problem here is clearly the syntax problem.

Additionally, you may want to consider modifying the following:

- `var $a;` is outdated, it should be `public $a` (or protected or private). `var` is still valid because it is backwards-compatible with PHP 4, but it is generally a bad idea.
- It is `__construct` not `_constructor`
- `a::method();` means "Call the static method of class a". You want something like 
   `$this->a = new a(); $this->a->method();`

Comment: It's not my project or code and the guy is using static calls and it worked with older php versions and I don't know the reason why he splits class a and b.

Answer (score 2):

You should **NOT** have dots (`.`) in class names.

And you might want to consider using an `autoloader`